# Latest known road condition

Tags: oracle, select, oracle-12c

**Table:**

I have a `road_condition_test` table:

```
create table road_condition_test (
    road_id int,
    age int,
    condition number(10,1)
);

insert into road_condition_test (road_id,age,condition) values ('500080',0,20);
insert into road_condition_test (road_id,age,condition) values ('500080',1,20);
insert into road_condition_test (road_id,age,condition) values ('500080',2,20);
insert into road_condition_test (road_id,age,condition) values ('500080',3,20);
insert into road_condition_test (road_id,age,condition) values ('500080',4,19.6);
insert into road_condition_test (road_id,age,condition) values ('500080',5,19.2);
insert into road_condition_test (road_id,age,condition) values ('500080',6,18.8);
insert into road_condition_test (road_id,age,condition) values ('500080',7,18.4);
insert into road_condition_test (road_id,age,condition) values ('500080',8,18);
insert into road_condition_test (road_id,age,condition) values ('500080',9,18);
insert into road_condition_test (road_id,age,condition) values ('500080',10,18);
insert into road_condition_test (road_id,age,condition) values ('500080',11,18);
insert into road_condition_test (road_id,age,condition) values ('500080',12,null);
insert into road_condition_test (road_id,age,condition) values ('500080',13,null);
insert into road_condition_test (road_id,age,condition) values ('500080',14,null);
insert into road_condition_test (road_id,age,condition) values ('500080',15,null);

insert into road_condition_test (road_id,age,condition) values ('500100',0,18);
insert into road_condition_test (road_id,age,condition) values ('500100',1,18.3);
insert into road_condition_test (road_id,age,condition) values ('500100',2,18.6);
insert into road_condition_test (road_id,age,condition) values ('500100',3,19);
insert into road_condition_test (road_id,age,condition) values ('500100',4,19);
insert into road_condition_test (road_id,age,condition) values ('500100',5,19);
insert into road_condition_test (road_id,age,condition) values ('500100',6,19);
insert into road_condition_test (road_id,age,condition) values ('500100',7,null);
insert into road_condition_test (road_id,age,condition) values ('500100',8,null);
insert into road_condition_test (road_id,age,condition) values ('500100',9,null);
insert into road_condition_test (road_id,age,condition) values ('500100',10,null);
insert into road_condition_test (road_id,age,condition) values ('500100',11,null);
insert into road_condition_test (road_id,age,condition) values ('500100',12,null);
insert into road_condition_test (road_id,age,condition) values ('500100',13,null);
insert into road_condition_test (road_id,age,condition) values ('500100',14,null);
insert into road_condition_test (road_id,age,condition) values ('500100',15,null);

commit;
```

---

```
   ROAD_ID        AGE  CONDITION
---------- ---------- ----------
    500080          0         20
    500080          1         20
    500080          2         20
    500080          3         20
    500080          4       19.6
    500080          5       19.2
    500080          6       18.8
    500080          7       18.4
    500080          8         18
    500080          9         18
    500080         10         18
    500080         11         18
    500080         12           
    500080         13           
    500080         14           
    500080         15           

    500100          0         18
    500100          1       18.3
    500100          2       18.6
    500100          3         19
    500100          4         19
    500100          5         19
    500100          6         19
    500100          7           
    500100          8           
    500100          9           
    500100         10           
    500100         11           
    500100         12           
    500100         13           
    500100         14           
    500100         15
```

---

**Question:**

I want to write a query that has a column called `latest_known_condition`.

For each road, the `latest_known_condition` column would contain the latest condition (according to `age`) that is not null.

Note: The **latest** condition is not to be confused with the **minimum** condition. Due to A) irregularities in inspections, and/or B) repairs to roads, the condition does not strictly go down over time (example: road `500100`).

The column would only be populated for rows **including and after** the latest known condition.

```
   ROAD_ID        AGE  CONDITION LATEST_KNOWN_CONDITION
---------- ---------- ---------- --------------------
    500080          0         20                   
    500080          1         20                   
    500080          2         20                   
    500080          3         20                   
    500080          4       19.6                   
    500080          5       19.2                   
    500080          6       18.8                   
    500080          7       18.4                   
    500080          8         18                   
    500080          9         18                   
    500080         10         18                   
    500080         11         18                   18
    500080         12                              18
    500080         13                              18
    500080         14                              18
    500080         15                              18

    500100          0         18                   
    500100          1       18.3                   
    500100          2       18.6                   
    500100          3         19                  
    500100          4         19                   
    500100          5         19                   
    500100          6         19                   19
    500100          7                              19
    500100          8                              19
    500100          9                              19
    500100         10                              19
    500100         11                              19
    500100         11                              19
    500100         12                              19
    500100         13                              19
    500100         14                              19
    500100         15                              19
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
  road_id,
  age,
  condition,
  case
    when (condition is null 
           or lead(condition) over (partition by road_id order by age) is null)
    then 
      last_value(condition ignore nulls) over (partition by road_id order by age)
    end
from
  road_condition_test
order by
 road_id, age, condition;

   ROAD_ID        AGE  CONDITION LATEST_KNOWN_CONDITION
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------------------
    500080          0         20                       
    500080          1         20                       
    500080          2         20                       
    500080          3         20                       
    500080          4       19.6                       
    500080          5       19.2                       
    500080          6       18.8                       
    500080          7       18.4                       
    500080          8         18                       
    500080          9         18                       
    500080         10         18                       
    500080         11         18                     18
    500080         12                                18
    500080         13                                18
    500080         14                                18
    500080         15                                18
    500100          0         18                       
    500100          1       18.3                       
    500100          2       18.6                       
    500100          3         19                       
    500100          4         19                       
    500100          5         19                       
    500100          6         19                     19
    500100          7                                19
    500100          8                                19
    500100          9                                19
    500100         10                                19
    500100         11                                19
    500100         12                                19
    500100         13                                19
    500100         14                                19
    500100         15                                19
```